# IsError() in Access VBA

Tags: vba, runtime-error

In my code I run a SQL statement in VBA like this:

```
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( SQL-Statement)
```

This SQL-Statement either returns one value or none.

I then want to check wether a value is returned or not.

```
  If IsError(rs.Fields("Name").Value) = True Then   
     MsgBox(Error)
  Else   
     Variable = rs.Fields("Name").Value
  End If
```

However: If there is an error the method IsError doesn't return true but the script says runtime-error 3021 and breaks.
Why does the method fail on this?

Unfortunately I have to write this on my mobile since I'm not allowed to log in on platforms from my work PC.

Ty all in Advance

Comment: You might need some real error handling? Like `On Error GoTo ExampleErr`, then under `ExampleErr:` put `MsgBox Err.Description`

Comment: `rs.EOF` will be true if no records returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the `EOF` property of the recordset.

Try this:

```
If Not rs.EOF Then Variable = rs.Fields("Name").Value
```

which is the same as

```
If Not rs.EOF Then Variable = rs![Name]
```